# React Image displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

When im deploying my website localy there is no problem at all viewing my images, but when im deploying my build it gets very bad.

```
<img src={require("../img/" + img.logo_src).default} alt={"logo"}></img>
```

How can i specify the source in the image tag to not be static/media in the build version?

This is how the html looks on the website

```
<img src="/static/media/img.PNG" alt="img logo">
```

Comment: What's the point of having these conditions? You are just returning in both the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let class A : which contains the biggest defining function
create an object of that class

```
A ob = new A();
A.biggest(value 1,value 2);
```

Store the result in some variable and use it in your current class......
eg

```
public int biggest(int x, int y)
{
   if(x>y)
   {     return(1);   }
   else
   {   return(0);      }
}
```

CLASS A:

```
int m = A.biggest(val 1,val 2);
System.out.print("Biggest Value "+m);
```

Let me know if this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your JTextField variable names are but the logic would be something like this:

```
int number1 = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
int number2 = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());

int max = 0;

if(number1 >= number2)
    max = number1;
else
    max = number2;

outputTextField.setText(max);
```